# Javascript passing through formatted int as string to function

Tags: javascript, php

So in PHP I have this variable

```
$studID
```

which can have formatted int values as "00-00000".

I want to pass this through to a Javascript function so I did this:

```
<?php ...
onclick="MyFunction('.$studID.')";
... ?>
```

This is the Javascript file:

```
function MyFunction(id1){
  alert("You have entered: " + id1);
}
```

My problem is that it returns an integer value of the first half minus the second half instead of the ID itself!

Example:

Passed through: 15-00788

Result from function: -773 (instead of 15-00788)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you looked at the page source, you'd see `onclick="MyFunction(15-00788)"`. JavaScript interprets `15-00788` as a mathematical operation. Try `onclick="MyFunction(' . json_encode($studID) . ')"` to quote the value properly as a string

Comment: @Phil It's not working! I tried json_encode with every variable I got and it seems to only work with pure integer values.

as of now I'm using the escape method by murrayju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell you exactly without the full context of the code, but the problem is that you need to surround the data with quotes to pass it into the JavaScript function as a string. Something like:

```
<?php ...
onclick="MyFunction(\''.$studID.'\')";
... ?>
```

Should probably work. (Have to be sure to properly escape the quote characters)

Also, you should consider using double quotes in php, which supports inline variable expansion (instead of doing concatenation). See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)